# react-virtualized InfiniteLoader in both directions, top and bottom

Tags: infinite-scroll, react-virtualized

How to make infinite scrolling in both directions, up and down. I am using the InfiniteLoader and the List, both are react-virtualized components. I have a list of timestamps with initial date-time range. From there the list should be infinite in both directions. Currently, scroll-down to the bottom of the List will trigger the function _loadMoreRows(). However, I would like to trigger the _loadMoreRows() with the same functionality when scrolling in the direction up.

Answer (score 6):

I have it working now :) Everything is fine. The `threshold` prop of the `<InfiniteLoader>` defines the threshold number of indices before the start/end of the `List` when to prefetch data, i.e. trigger `_loadMoreRows()`.

The first and the last item in `this.state.items` should have their corresponding `loadedRowsMap` set to `undefined` after the initial data fetch.

```
    const items = _getItems(); // fetch items
    const rowCount = items.length;
    const loadedRowsMap = [];
    _.map(this.state.loadedRowsMap,(row,index)=>{
      const status = (index===0 || index===rowCount-1) ? undefined : STATUS_LOADED;
      loadedRowsMap.push(status)});
    scrollToIndex = parseInt(rowCount/2,10);
    this.setState({
      items, rowCount, loadedRowsMap, scrollToIndex,
    });
```

Before displaying the list, a `scrollToIndex` prop of the `<List>` component should be set to the middle of the list, i.e. `rowCount/2`. This number should satisfy the equation

```
    0 + threshold < scrollToIndex < rowCount - 1 - threshold.
```

Function `_isRowLoaded()` will check `loadedRowsMap[index]`. If it is set to `STATUS_LOADED` or `STATUS_LOADING` (internal constants used inside the `InfiniteLoader`) it will not trigger `_loadMoreRows()`. If it is set to `undefined`, then it will trigger `_loadMoreRows()`.

With this setup, trigering `_loadMoreRows()` works in both scroll directions, up and down.

Comment: I did the same but cannot get the list to stay at its current scroll position after an add of elements at the top. can you share a piece of code of how you did it?

Comment: Hello! Was wondering if there's a way to have a working code demo to use as an example? It's exactly what I need, but unsure how to absorb this information as it is.